# Which probabilites are to be supplied to rcorr.cens and improveProb in package Hmisc?

Tags: r, predictive-models, survival, model-evaluation

Both functions are great for comparing, for example, survival models. The first especially for computing Harrell's C-index, the second for NRI and IDI.

However, it looks like `rcorr.cens` takes survival probabilities and `improveProb` takes event probabilites, that is, 1 - survival probabilities, as arguments. Could somebody confirm this? It just feels weird, and I haven't been able to find information on it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

rcorr.cens can take either survival probabilities or event probabilities (better known as risks). The resulting c index will = (1 - c index), when the survival/risks are used.

I do not know about improveProb.